# The secure enough and simplest way of authentication for SPA

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I'm looking for a good process of authentication in a SPA.
I think that the process what dewastator describes [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951509/token-authentication-in-spa-app) seems good but the process of [the article](https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/) what thierry templier presentes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958920/827804) seems more complex as it uses 'mac_key', 'refresh_token' and so on.
Is it not enough just to use login ID, password and access token for authentication? I'm not thinking to make APIs enable cross origin requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply exchange username & password for an access token.  This is the [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).  This really is the simplest way to secure a Single Page App (SPA).

I recommend using JWT for the token format and HTTPS-Only cookies as the secure storage mechanism.  I've covered these topics in my recent blog article, [Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa)

Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com).  We've been doing a lot of work with SPAs, and we have a full-stack javascript solution for token authentication in our [Stormpath Angular SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs)

Comment: Thanks! Perfect!. I thought that saving security roles in database per user record was enough but after read the usage of JWT in your blog, I agree saving that kind of information in tokens is a great idea.